# How do I get my git merge conflicts back after merging incorrectly?

Tags: git, merge

I'm trying to merge 2 branches that have a lot of changes in them, several with merge conflicts.  I merged the files using `git mergetool`, but I've subsequently realized that I merged a couple of them incorrectly.  I basically want to go back to the conflicted state for those couple files, so I can re-run the mergetool and correct my errors.  I don't want to throw away my entire merge, since most of it is correct.

I've tried resetting to my head and then doing `git checkout -m other_branch -- my_file` to no avail.  I ended up resetting to HEAD, getting the file out of the other branch, and just doing `git add --patch` on the file, only staging what I wanted.  But there must be a better way...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, check out if you have conflicted state in the index (*before resetting to HEAD*), via

```
$ git ls-files --stage --abbrev my_file
```

You should get something like the following:

```
100644 257cc56  1        my_file
100644 b7d6715 2        my_file
100644 5716ca5  3        my_file
```

If you don't get that, you would have to use `git update-index`, like [Charles Bailey said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677049/how-do-i-get-my-git-merge-conflicts-back-after-merging-incorrectly/1679900#1679900), or use temporary files.  If you have that, then

```
$ git checkout -m my_file
```

should work (I have checked this).

Comment: Just tried `git checkout -m` and it works even if I only get one one staged file version (i.e. after `git add` or successful use of `git mergetool`). Maybe that's a newer Git feature (I'm using 2.1.3).

Answer (score 6):

You *can* do this with `git update-index` using either the `--cacheinfo` or `--index-info` options to remove the `0` entry in the index for a given file and populating the `1`, `2` and `3` entries with the base, local and remote versions respectively but it is going to be fiddly.

It's probably going to be easier to extract the various versions to temporary files, and manually run your merge tool, writing the answer to the correct file and adding the result of the successful merge.

e.g.

```
git show $(git merge-base HEAD MERGE_HEAD):file >base-file
git show HEAD:file >local-file
git show MERGE_HEAD:file >remote-file
```

Run mergetool manually, writing to `file`.

```
git add file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
git checkout [--ours|--theirs|--merge] <paths>
```

to checkout the path(s) as found on the branch being merged into or from or to recreate the conflicting merge.

The git-checkout manpage has a bit more on this issue.

As Charles Bailey pointed out this does not work when the merged file has already been added to the index.  I played around a bit and here is a script that should do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Distributed under the GNU General Public License, version 2.0.
#
# git-goat:
#
#   Restore a merge conflict, after it has already been resolved.

# Lifted from contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
__gitdir ()
{
    if [ -z "${1-}" ]; then
        if [ -n "${__git_dir-}" ]; then
            echo "$__git_dir"
        elif [ -d .git ]; then
            echo .git
        else
            git rev-parse --git-dir 2>/dev/null
        fi
    elif [ -d "$1/.git" ]; then
        echo "$1/.git"
    else
        echo "$1"
    fi
}

into=$(git describe --all HEAD)
from=$(cat $(__gitdir)/MERGE_HEAD)
base=$(git merge-base $into $from)

case "$1" in --ours|--theirs|--merge) whose=$1; shift; esac

[ -z "$1" ] && echo "fatal: at least one file has to be specified" && exit

for file in "$@"
do
    (
        echo -e "0 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000\t$file"
        git ls-tree $base $file | sed -e "s/\t/ 1\t/"
        git ls-tree $into $file | sed -e "s/\t/ 2\t/"
        git ls-tree $from $file | sed -e "s/\t/ 3\t/"
    ) | git update-index --index-info
    git checkout ${whose:-"--merge"} $file
done
```

Note that I haven't tested this much.  If you find any problems or have other improvements [here](http://gist.github.com/245897) is a forkable "gist".

Comment: It's porbably worth noting this only works if you didn't exit your mergetool, saving 'successfully' as this causes mergetool to 'add' the resolved file and remove the conflicted entries from the index.

Comment: Charles Bailey, are you sure, what you are saying is correct? The script to me very much looks like exactly restoring the index to the state /before/ add was done! It is not referring to :{1,2,3}: initially but rather adressing the commits via HEAD, MERGE_HEAD and `merge-base...`.

Comment: @TilmanVogel: Please check the version of the answer that I commented on, not the update in response to my comment.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Oh, sorry, I didn't pay attention to the history. He even mentions your comment in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally accept say yes to the conflict resolved prompt without saving the changes from mergetool, I think you can just stash the staged changes and redo the merge.

```
git stash
git merge <other branch>
```